# Index value considered significantly different from 0?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I have just developed a formula (of which I could give the different elements which compose it if need be) allowing to quantify the tolerance of an individual to the exposure. This gives me an index that can fluctuate from -1 to 1 (-1 The individual is not tolerant at all, 1 he is very tolerant, 0 there is no effect of the disturbance on the tolerance). I applied this formula for all my individuals. What I would like to know is if there is a threshold value, allowing me to assert statistically, that beyond or below this threshold the value of my index is different from 0.

For example, for individuals whose tolerance index = 0.09 or = -0.12, the values being close to 0, I would like to know if I can consider them as very slightly tolerant and slightly intolerant respectively, or if the values are too close to 0 and that it is therefore necessary to consider that there is no effect of the disturbance on the tolerance for these individuals.

to clarify, What I would like to know is what test to perform to assert if values very close to 0, positive or negative, will be considered significantly far enough from 0 or too close, implying that we interpret the result as if it were a 0.

I don't really know which statistical test on R is the most relevant to use in this case, and if you have any suggestions on how to apply it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This platform is more for programming related questions. I've voted to move this question to the Cross-Validated forum, where it is more appropriate.

Comment: I understand, no problem.

Comment: As stated, this question is not a statistical one, it's a biological one.  That you believe it has a statistical element suggests the tolerances are uncertain data, or random samples of something.  To address that we would need to know what those data are and something about how data determine, or allow you to estimate, the tolerances.

Comment: Ok I'll try to clarify, because it's more of a statistical question that need a biological context. I have a given territory that contains 10 individuals in captivity. The territory is divided into 3 zones, P1/P2 and Dist. The first two are exposed areas and Dist is a never exposed area. It is a question of exposure to visitors who can be in two different places: V1 and V2, visitors in V1 can observe in the P1 area, visitors in V2 can observe in the V2 area. From the number of observations of each individual in each zone and for each type of possible visitor presence/absence configuration (whi

Comment: @Hugo Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.  That will enable you to include this information in your original post.